# rename directory of images numeric

Tags: bash, rename

I'm trying to rename a directory full of images like so:

> test.jpg
>   funny.gif
>   sad.png
>   filename.PNG
>   filenaaskjas.JPG

to:

> 1.jpg
>   2.gif
>   3.png
>   4.png
>   5.jpg

I've got it working except for the uppercase --> lowercase conversion:

```
i=1;
shopt -s nullglob;
for f in *.jpg *.gif *.png *.jpeg *.JPG *.JPEG *.GIF; do
    mv -- "$f" "$i.${f##*.}";
    ((i++));
done
```

I also want `jpeg` to become `jpg`.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like

```
ext=$( echo "$i.${f##*.}" | tr [A-Z] [a-z] )
mv -- "$f" $i$ext
```

or for fixed length file names.

```
dest=$(printf '08d%' $9)$( echo "$i.${f##*.}" | tr [A-Z] [a-z] )
mv -- "$f" $dest
```

c

Answer (score 2):

You can use `${parameter/pattern/string}` to search/replace and `${parameter,,pattern}` to convert to lowercase.

```
i=1;
shopt -s nullglob;
for f in *.jpg *.gif *.png *.jpeg *.JPG *.JPEG *.GIF; do
    EXT="${f##*.}"
    EXT=${EXT,,}
    EXT=${EXT/jpeg/jpg}
    mv -- "$f" "$i.${EXT}";
    ((i++));
done
```

Comment: Requires, I believe, bash v4 for `${parameter,,pattern}`

Comment: @glenn: Correct. If on bash 3, there's always `EXT=$(echo $EXT|tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]')`

Answer (score 2):

Two steps:

convert extensions:

```
for file in *.GIF; do mv $file ${file%GIF}gif; done
for file in *.jpeg; do mv $file ${file%jpeg}jpg; done
...
```

number files:

```
for file in *.gif *.jpg ...; do mv $file $i$file; ((i++)); done
```

Comment: the second step run by itself (I didn't need extensions); only added numbers to the beginning of the filename, didn't replace the filename. Luckily it was a test run.

Answer (score 1):

If you have (p)rename, you can write this:

```
shopt -s nullglob;

i=1; 
for f in *.{jpg,JPG,jpeg,JPEG,png,PNG,gif,GIF}; do 
    rename 's/.*\.(.*)$/'$((i++))'.\L$1/; s/jpeg$/jpg/' "$f"; 
done
```

Comment: Simpler: `rename 'next unless -e; ++$i; s/.*\.(.*)$/$i.\L$1/; s/jpeg$/jpg/' *.{jpg,JPG,jpeg,JPEG,png,PNG,gif,GIF}`. You don't need the shell loop since Perl can do the counting, and you don't need `nullglob` because `rename` ignores nonexistent file names.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know rename could understand other (besides s/// and y///) perl commands  too.