# Rename Files to Consecutive Integers

Tags: bash, shell-script, files, rename

I have bunch of files in one directory, like these:

```
0002.b3120c4bcbf3101e661161ee7efcb8bf
0003.acfc5ad94bbd27118a0d8685d18c89dd
0004.e8d5727378ddde5c3be181df593f1712
0005.8c3b9e9c0f3f183ddaf7592a11b99957
```

And so on...

And I want to rename them to something easier to manipulate in a script:

```
2
3
4
5
```

And so on...

How to do it in Linux shell or script?

Comment: see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/7446/22142 or https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/420927/22142 or https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/281794/22142 or https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/26474/22142 etc

Comment: "easier to manipulate in a script" may translate to wanting the files in the same order, in which case you may want leading zeroes?

Comment: Well, not really, they could even be shuffled, don't matter.

Comment: are the "2 3 4 5" new filenames supposed to correspond to the leading part of the originals? or just start at 2 arbitrarily?

Comment: Could even start arbitrary, they will be shuffled in next stage of work anyway

Answer (score -2):

Thanks to the second link ([Batch rename files to a sequential numbering](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/420927/batch-rename-files-to-a-sequential-numbering)) provided by @don_crissti in the first comment, problem solved.
Cheers.

Comment: Two downgrades! LOL